# How can I write an alias of Raku regexes?

Tags: alias, grammar, raku

I wrote a grammar like this:

```
grammar StatementFormat {
    token TOP { (<plain> | '%' <placeholder>)* }

    token plain { <-[%]> }

    token placeholder {
        | <verb>
        | <noun>
        | <adverb>
    }

    token verb {
        'v'
        {
            # some actions
        }
    }

    token noun {
        'n'
        {
            # some actions
        }
    }

    token adverb {
        'a'
        {
            # some actions
        }
    }
}
```

So I could use it to parse strings like "someone %v %n %a".

However, I found there were so many usages like "%v %n %a", I'd like to give it an alias, say, "%b" such that parsing "someone %b" is equivalent to parsing "someone %v %n %a".

So is there a way to do that?

Of course, `token alias { 'b' { ... } }` can do that. But in that way I need to repeat that action code. I am wondering if there exists a simpler way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, there is one obvious way, which is to simply put the code for the actions into subroutines and then in the `b` alias, call them:

```
sub verb-action($/) { }
sub noun-action($/) { }
sub adverb-action($/) { }

grammar StatementFormat {
    # rest goes here

    token verb {
        'v'
        { verb-action($/) }
    }

    token noun {
        'n'
        { noun-action($/) }
    }

    token adverb {
        'a'
        { adverb-action($/) }
    }

    token alias {
        'b'
        {
            verb-action($/);
            noun-action($/);
            adverb-action($/);
        }
    }
}
```

But where'd be the fun of that?

Instead, I'd recommend using the built-in [a*ction object* feature of grammars](https://docs.raku.org/language/grammar_tutorial#Grammar_actions).

It goes like this: you have a separate class with the actions as methods, with the same name as the grammar actions:

```
class StatementFormatActions {
    method verb($/) { ... }
    method noun($/) { ... }
    method adverb($/) { ... }

}
```

And when you call `parse`, you pass an instance of that action class along:

```
StatementFormat.parse($string, :actions(StatementFormatActions.new));
```

Then when you introduce the `alias` token, you can also introduce an `alias` method:

```
method alias($/) {
    self.verb($/);
    self.noun($/);
    self.adverb($/);
}
```

Inside the actions you can also call `make` or `$/.make(...)` to attach the result of your actions to the match object (then available in`$/.made`) to populate an AST from your parse tree.

(You might also like [my book on grammars](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484232279) which has several examples and more in-depth explanations. Sorry for the plug, could not resist).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Besides, I am wondering if it's possible to modify the string during parsing. If I can replace the `%b` with `%v %n %a`, then it's quite easy to implement the alias. But it seems raku does not support this feature. Do you think it useful?

Comment: @lovetomato strings are immutable in Raku, so you cannot modify it while parsing.